# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Browser Error

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, dns-hosting

domain

www.polydevs.co.uk

I recently moved servers, and moved domain hosting. Since then I've had no luck getting my website active.

Here's how the server is setup

[DNS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l77cO.png)

So this is on my server. However, after 24 hours I still receive ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in my browser when I try to load it. I've tried clearing dns cache in chrome but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried looking up things with nslookup/host to see what's wrong?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Loop detected! We were referred back to '23.72.2.225' was all I found. Could this be with the domain hosting end of things?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Further digging resulted in inability to resolve www.polydevs.co.uk to an IP address.

Comment: I just tried host -t ns polydevs.co.uk and it could not resolve.

Comment: BTW - two NSes in the same net is **The Bad Idea (tm)** - some time ago it was even prohibited by registrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whois info for polydevs.co.uk shows you are not using the correct name servers

http://www.nominet.uk/whois/?query=polydevs.co.uk#whois-results

```
Name servers:
    ns1.polydevs.co.uk        23.72.2.225
    ns2.polydevs.co.uk        23.72.2.225
```

You'll need to contact your registrar to verify the name servers are updated to match your new ones and that nothing else is wrong.

Comment: My domain registrar and uncontactable.. Worst support I've ever received. So is this on there end? Do I need them to set private nameservers?

Comment: @RyanBabchshin ^^^

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer

Comment: @RyanBabchshin Thanks for your answer. I'll try again to get in contact with them, time to take it to twitter.

Comment: @RyanBabchshin Could you take another look at the whois and tell me if it's correct now? Whilst I'm in contact with them.

Comment: @Daniel It looks fine now